# Informix external table pass file name as parameter

Tags: informix

I have a stored procedure in Informix that uses external tables to unload data to a disk file from a select statement. Is it possible to give the DISK file name as a parameter to the stored procedure? My stored procedure is as follows:

```
create procedure spUnloadData(file_name_param varchar(64))

create temp table temp_1(
        col_11 smallint
    ) with no log;

    INSERT INTO temp_1 select col1 from data_table;

    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE temp1_ext 
    SAMEAS temp_1
    USING (
        --DATAFILES ("DISK:/home/informix/temp.dat") 
          DATAFILES("DISK:" || file_name_param )
        );

    INSERT INTO temp1_ext SELECT * FROM temp_1;

    DROP  TABLE temp1_ext ;
    DROP  TABLE temp_1;

END PROCEDURE;
```

I am trying to pass in the DISK filename as a parameter(from my shell script, timestamped).
Any help is appreciated.
NH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use Dynamic SQL in the stored procedure — for example, the [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0767.htm) statement.

You create a string containing the text of the SQL and then execute it. Adapting your code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spUnloadData(file_name_param VARCHAR(64))

    DEFINE stmt VARCHAR(255);  -- LVARCHAR might be safer

    CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_1(
        col_11 SMALLINT
    ) WITH NO LOG;

    INSERT INTO temp_1 select col1 from data_table;

    LET stmt = 'CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE temp1_ext ' ||
               'SAMEAS temp_1 USING  DATAFILES("DISK:' ||
               TRIM(file_name_param) ||
               '")';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;

    INSERT INTO temp1_ext SELECT * FROM temp_1;

    DROP TABLE temp1_ext;
    DROP TABLE temp_1;

END PROCEDURE;
```

<sup>*Untested code — the concept should be sound, though.*</sup>

This assumes you are using a reasonably current version of Informix; the necessary feature is in 12.10, and some version 11.70 versions too, I believe.

Comment: Thank you. I will try your solution out.

Comment: Your solution worked. I forgot I could use execute immediate stmt to execute dynamic statements.

Answer (score 0):

I made slight changes to my code to unload data(as Informix default '|' separated fields). Instead of using a temp table, I was able to select columns directly into an external table dynamically.